# parsing data from one table to another table

Tags: plsql

I am trying to write a query to copy data from one table to another table in PL/SQL and I need help, thanks.

Source table has single field and destination has 3 fields. 
Data in the source table starts with 05, 10, 30 1nd 99 as below

```
05-1   
10-1
30-1
10-2
30-2
30-2
30-2
30-2
10-3
30-3
99-1 
05-2
10-4
30-4
```

need to copy data into another table with 3 columns as below

```
A      B      C
05-1   10-1   30-1
05-1   10-2   30-2
05-1   10-2   30-2
05-1   10-2   30-2
05-1   10-2   30-2
05-1   10-3   30-3 
05-2   10-4   30-4
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then reword your question.  It is not clear what you are looking for.  Please show clear before and after examples.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but at a guess from the input and output you have provided I am assuming that the rules to generate the output are somthing along the lines of the below.

1) when it starts with 99 ignore it

2) when it starts with 05 set variable and move on to next row.

3) when it starts with 10 set variable and move on to next row.

4) when it starts with 30 insert into tables using the variables you have set in previous 2 steps.

If the above rules are correct the below should work. Of course you will need to substitute in your table / field names.  If I have misunderstood your requirements from the data provided (quite likely as it is not very clear), this should at least give you a starting point to work from.

```
declare 

cursor c_loops is
select column1 from table1;

v_col1 varchar2(10) default null;
v_col2 varchar2(10) default null;
v_col3 varcahr2(10) default null;

begin
  for v_row in c_loops loop
     case (substr(v_row.column1, 0, 2) 
       when '99' then
          -- do nothing ignore row
          null;
       when '05' then
          v_col1 := v_row.column1;
       when '10' then
          v_col2 := v_row.column1;
       when '30' then
          v_col3 := v_row.column1;
          insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3) values (v_col1, v_col2, v_col3);
       else
         -- output some error here because you have unexpected input
         null;
     end case;
  end loop;
end;
```